# how to check whether web socket is active or not using SRWebsocket

Tags: ios, websocket

I'm using SRWebsocket for socket connection. Now I'm calling socket open function whenever the app enter foreground, But i don't want to do that. I need to check first whether the connection is active or not then only open the websocket. Is there any way to do that?

```
- (void)connectWebSocket {


if( self.readyState == SR_OPEN){

    NSLog(@"CONNECT%u ",self.readyState);
} else {

    NSLog(@"CLOSED %u",self.readyState);

}





[[IXDataBaseManager sharedNetworkDataManager] deleteOldPolls];


NSString *urlString =@"wss://m.hol.com/testing/api/ws/"; 



if( self.webSocket ) {
    [self.webSocket close];
    self.webSocket.delegate = nil;
    self.webSocket=nil;
}
self.webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] protocols:@[@"hol-json"]];
self.webSocket.delegate = self;
[self.webSocket open];
NSLog(@"CONNECTOPN%u ",self.readyState);

}
```

self.readyState always return "0"

Comment: You can use property `readyState` of SRWebsocket to check the current state of the socket. Here are the possible state of any socket 
`typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SRReadyState) {
    SR_CONNECTING   = 0,
    SR_OPEN         = 1,
    SR_CLOSING      = 2,
    SR_CLOSED       = 3,
};
`

Comment: Where should i use this code? in appdelegate?

Comment: Anywhere you want to check the state before preforming any action.

Comment: I'm little confused, can you write down that code snippet ? I have found same code inside of SRWebsocket. So how can I create another function inside of my class?

Comment: updated question, please have a look?

Comment: self.readyState '0' means its connecting.

Comment: but it always shows connecting even i closed websocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this sample code help you:

```
- (void)openSocket {
    if (_webSocket.readyState == SR_CLOSED)
    {
        // _websocket is closed. Open your web socket again
        [_webSocket open];
    } else {
        // _websocket is not closed. check the readyState and perform your task accordingly
    }
}

- (void)forceOpenSocket {
    _webSocket.delegate = nil;
    [_webSocket close];

    _webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Input Url"]]];
    _webSocket.delegate = self;

    // Opening Connection ...
    [_webSocket open];
}
```

Comment: Still getting "0" connecting state

Comment: The default state of webSocket is `SR_CONNECTING` thats why its by default return '0'. To check open you can use other state like `SR_CLOSED`  or `SR_CLOSING`

Comment: It return SR_CONNECTING always. +1 @VijayMasiwal